# TFS to GitHub Migration

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, migration, git-tfs

I am working on Migrating my Azure DevOps code to GitHub. 
I am using the https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs tool to migrate the source code from ADO to GitHub.

I am able to successfully migrate the code with Changeset History etc, I only see the git commit id and my git-tfs-id contains only the ADO Url, Changeset id and the path to repo but I don't see the TFS work item linked to the Changeset in GitHub.

Can someone help me on how to copy the history of Work Item linked to my TFS changeset to GitHub.

Comment: If I understand well, you want to migrate the workitems to create GitHub issues, right!?! I don't know a tool that does that. You will have to write a program that will request the TFS api to retrieve the data and use the GitHub api to create the issues...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to migrate the work items to create GitHub issues.

*Philippe* is the author of git-tfs tool. Just like he pointed out, unfortunately there isn't any tool or simple way to migrate the GitHub issues to Azure DevOps.

As we can see the issues in GitHub and the work items in Azure DevOps are using totally different templates.

If you are talking about work item links for commit. You could try to run `git-tfs` with the `--export` option.

Take a look at this similar question here: [Clone a TFVC repository (to GIT) with work item links intact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39506277/clone-a-tfvc-repository-to-git-with-work-item-links-intact)